# Scala App doesn't exit even though Future is completed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, concurrent.futures

I wait for a Future to complete and print the content on the console. Even when everything is finished, the main application doesn't exit and I have to kill it manually.

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit {
    val req = HttpRequest(GET, myURL)
    val res = Http().singleRequest(req)
    val resultsFutures = Future {
        val resultString = Await.result(HttpRequests.unpackResponse(res), Duration.Inf)
        JsonMethods.parse(resultString).extract[List[Results]]
    }
    val results = Await.result(resultsFutures, Duration.Inf)
    println(results)
}
```

So `results` gets printed on the console with the expected contend, but the application still doesn't end.
Is there something I can do to exit the application? Is there still something running, that the main is waiting for?

I'm using:

- scala 2.12.10
- akka 2.5.26
- akkaHttp 10.1.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using Akka, you likely have an `ActorSystem` instantiated somehow under the hood that will keep the process running.

Either you are able to get a hand on it and call its `actorSystem.terminate()` method, or you can also use an explicit `sys.exit(0)` at the end of your main method (`0` being the exit code you want).

Edit: you should also wrap the `Await`s in `Try` and make sure to call `sys.exit` in case of failures as well.

Comment: Yes, I do have a `implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()` in the object that is running the main.

Comment: Changing it to explicit `val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()`. Then I called `system.terminate()` (.shutdown is deprecated), but this still doesn't end the Application. Is there another way than calling `sys.exit(0)` as it seems brute forced and there should be a intended way?

Comment: My mistake, had to catch all implicit ActorSystems in all functions and terminate them after they finished their job. Well done, this is the right answer.